# Is there a way to hide a cell in a UITableView (Grouped)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, hide

As described in the title, I want to hide a cell and not remove it from the table. Is there a way to go about doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by hiding it .Do you dont want to show the contents of that cell or you dont want to show the cell itself.

Comment: Or, You'd like to disable the user interaction?

Comment: This question was already asked and answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071962/can-i-show-hide-a-certain-cell-in-an-uitableview-depending-on-the-state-of-anothe.

Comment: I did and saw the question. But the answer tells me how to insert or delete rows which is not the solution I am looking for. I want to hide the cell and not remove it

Comment: What do you mean by hiding? Just so the cell doesn't show up on a certain occasion or what triggers the hiding of the cell?

Comment: you just commented on your question that you want to remove the cell, but 2 mins ago you commented on my answer that you want to hide it and not remove it. It's a bit confusing to be honest.

Comment: I meant I want to hide the cell and not remove it

Comment: Sorry edited my comment. I just want to hide it and NOT remove it

Answer (score 0):

You can use next: set variable that handle cell state (hidden or not):

```
     - (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == _cellRow)
        return _cellHidden ? 0.0f : _cellHeight;
}
```

And when you want to hide or show cell ask to reload it. This will trigger previous method.

```
_cellHidden = YES;
[_tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] 
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]
```